# upload image from view to controller mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

Good day,

I am trying to upload an image from my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CrearCurso", "ProfesorCurso", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Upload Image</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                Browse… <input type="file" id="imgInp">
            </span>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>
    <img id='img-upload'/>
</div>
}
```

I have this controller in mvc

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CrearCurso(CursoViewModel CursoViewModel, HttpPostedFileBase imgInp)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

However when I inspect the HttpPsotedFileBase, it is empty. What is wrong here? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms posts back the name/value pairs of its successful form controls. Your file input has no `name` attribute. Change it to

```
<input type="file" name="imgInp">
```

However, its better to strongly bind to your model, so add a

```
public HttpPostedFileBase ImgInp { get; set; }
```

property to your view model and use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImgInp, new { type = "file" })
```

which will also allow you to add validation attributes to your file input if required

Comment: thank you very much, for simplicity I did not add it to a viewmodel

Comment: Why would you think that is simpler?

Comment: simpler for this example maybe